# Python: How to read variable file names in a loop

Tags: python, json, loops, variables

I have various JSON files on my drive that I would like to process in a loop, but how can I read them in a loop?

Basically I have a list where all filenames are included and all files are also in one folder.

The objective is to create lists out the json files in a loop.

```py
TestList = ["cats", "dogs"]

for i in TestList:
    with open ("{i}.json") as {i}_file:
        print({i}_file)
```

Unfortunately I get syntax errors no matter how I try it.

Thank you so much in advance for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
TestList = ["cats", "dogs"]

for i in TestList:
    with open(f"{i}.json") as fp:
        print(fp.read())
```

First, if you use `"{i}.json"`, add the prefix `f` to define this string as [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

Then your variable `{i}_file` can't be dynamically evaluated to create the variables `cats_file` and `dogs_file`. You have to use a static name.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot - is it possible on the list level to create a dynamic name like: {i}_list_of_lists = [] ?

or even better on a data frame level like df_{i}_list_of_lists?

Comment: No it's not recommended to do that (but it's possible). The preferred way is to use a dict `my_dict` and `my_dict[i] = ...`